# How do i get my SHAP plot to display more than 20 variables?

Tags: python, shap

How do i get my SHAP plot to display more than 20 variables in my chart.  Here is my code:

```
shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train)
plt.savefig(Config.CLASH_PATH + '/plots/shap_' + target_cols + '.png')
plt.close()
```

[SHAP graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLTJX.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use option `max_display=30` in `shap.summary_plot()`.

Comment: You should accept your own answer (nothing wrong with that), so that the question does not appear still open.